# MEF Importing ViewModel that needs data, to View for Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, parameters, viewmodel, mef

I'm not sure the best way to get this accomplished. Here's my view:

```
public partial class MyPage : Page
{
    [Import]
    public MyVM ViewModel
    {
        get { return DataContext as MyVM ; }
        set { DataContext = value; }
    }

    public String EventName { get; set; }
    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CompositionInitializer.SatisfyImports(this);
    }

    // Executes when the user navigates to this page.
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {       }
}
```

And my VM:

```
[Export]
public class MyVM : ViewModelBase
{
    public MyVM ()
    {

    }
}
```

This works great. However, I need to get data from either the viewmodel that has my string, or the URL. Either way, I'm not sure the best way to get the string to MyVW using MEF.
I thought ok I'll use Messaging from MVVMLight, but the MyVM class isn't instantiated yet to receive the broadcast from the other ViewModel. So then I thought well, I'll try this:

```
[Export]
public class MyVM : ViewModelBase
{
    public MyVM ([Import("hello")]string hello)
    {

    }
}
```

and then put this in the view:

```
[Export("hello")]
public String MyHello { get; set; }
```

but that gave me an error. Cannot call SatisfyImports on a object of type 'Form A' because it is marked with one or more ExportAttributes.

So what's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: You want to pass data to you vm from where?

Comment: @derek-beattie Either from another viewmodel or from the view (from the URL)

Answer (score 0):

To share data between views I usually inject a SharedData object into my ViewModels.

```
 [Import(RequiredCreationPolicy = CreationPolicy.Shared)]
 public ISharedData SharedData { get; set; }
```

I'm also using the Caliburn Micro framework so I'm not passing data around via the URL querystring.  By convention CM will parse out URL parameters and inject them into properties on your VM but I'm not sure if this functionality only applies to Windows Phone development.

from [here](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Working%20with%20Windows%20Phone%207%20v1.1&referringTitle=Documentation)

> Examine the Page’s QueryString. Look
>   for properties on the VM that match
>   the QueryString parameters and inject
>   them, performing the necessary type
>   coercion.

When you say you want to possibly pass data from the view to the vm, that should happen through databinding.

Comment: I am aware that databinding should be used for sending data to the viewmodel from the view. Essentially what I want is the user to be able go to www.hello.com/NewPage/XYZ and have the parameter XYZ from URI used in the view model. I can get the XYZ with the OnNavigatedTo function with e.URI.ToString() and parse it out there, but then it's in the CodeBehind and by the time I do that MEF has already instantiated the ViewModel and I would like that XYZ parameter to be in the parameter of the constructor of the VM.

Comment: So you need to bind NavigationContext.  Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020081/mvvm-silverlight-and-page-navigation

Comment: I've tried implementing that method, and it makes sense, however the property in my viewmodel for the NavigationContext never gets set to anything.
'xmlns:helper="clr-namespace:MyApp.Helpers"
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource VMLocator}, Converter={StaticResource VMIndexerConverter}, ConverterParameter=MyViewModel}"
xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
helper:Navigator.Source="{Binding}"'

Nothing in the Navigator Attached Property gets called either, but my VM is still getting instantiated.

Comment: I tried setting that, with the path set to my property on my viewmodel, that would call the get, but still wouldn't set it to anything.