# Silverlight Page Navigation with usercontrol and MVVM Light

Tags: silverlight, mvvm-light

I'm developing a silerlight application and have settled on the MVVM Light framework.  One of the things I'm trying to do is create a "LoginStatus" control that can be used on multiple locations because we have different layouts that the pages are grouped into.

My challenge is how to redirect the page from a user control.  When the users "logout" I want to redirect them to a different page not just a different View.  Anybody have any thoughts or some examples that might do something like this.

Most of the examples I have seen out there just change the status on the current view.

dbl

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to navigate to a new page - i.e. leaving the silverlight application - you can use the `Navigate` method of the `System.Windows.Browser.HtmlWindow` class ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190502%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)).

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(
    new Uri("http://silverlight.net")
);
```

Otherwise, if you do not want to leave the silverlight application you simply navigate to a default view that informs the user that he is not logged in.

**Edit**:

For implementing a navigation service in Silverlight see for example [this post](http://garfoot.com/blog/2010/09/silverlight-navigation-with-the-mvvm-pattern/) or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020081/mvvm-silverlight-and-page-navigation).

Comment: Ok, but what is the mechanism for navigating to another view or to change the main page with a different layout and navigation:Fram from within a usercontrol?  I don't want to leave silverlight but I want to change either the one in the code.  Its easy enough to use a hyperlink or hyperlink button on a user control to set the NavigationUri but I want to do it either from a View or ViewModel.

Comment: @dblwizard: see edit. These are samples of how it can be done, but there are multiple ways. Personally, in one of my projects I adapted [Laurents approach](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2011/01/06/navigation-in-a-wp7-application-with-mvvm-light.aspx) for WP7 to Silverlight via an attached property, but I have no writeup available ... :-(

Comment: Obalix, the problem with all these examples is that the views are of type "Page" but the MVVM Light Toolkit uses a "UserControl" for each "View".  I still am not seeing how from code you can change the view.  Or change the Master page to get a different look.

Comment: MVVM Light is not bound to a specific View control. You are free to use what ever you want, e.g.. UserControl, Page, Window, PivotPage, and so on. Just create a page and set the DataContext as you would with the UserControl.

Comment: I think I must not be explaining my problem correctly.  I understand I can use the Page or the UserControl for a view and that all works fine.  My challenge is how from code behind or viewmodel of UserControl do navigate to a new view.  You don't have access to the NavigationService.

Comment: @dblwizard see the two posts in my first edit ... they both deal with this.